# How to remove select option in IE without triggering onchange event

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, onchange

I am working on an application in Wicket. All my dropdowns have a default option "Choose one".
When the user change the value, some javascript remove the "Choose one" option.

Some of my dropdown also have ajax onchange event (Wicket onchange behavior).

My problem is that, with Internet Explorer (7 and 8), removing the "choose one" default option will trigger the onchange event.

So, all my dropdown with ajax listener are called twice. First ajax call is fired by the framework and then the javascript will remove the option causing a second onchange event.

In firefox per exemple, my ajax listener is only called once. Removing the option is not triggering the onchange witch is ok.

javascript code:

```
var comboboxes = $("select:not(.emptyOptionEnhanced, .noRemoveEmptyChoice)");
comboboxes.each(function() {
    var combo = $(this);
    var emptyOptions = combo.find("option[value='']");

    if (emptyOptions.length) {
        combo.debug("Enhancing combo box with empty option");
        combo.change(function(e) {
        emptyOptions.debug("Removing empty option").remove();
    });
).addClass("emptyOptionEnhanced");
```